# Behaviour of my Battery Management System Schematic

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lipo

I am trying to validate my schematic of a battery management system based on the [DW01A](https://jlcpcb.com/partdetail/PUOLOP-DW01A/C351410) for single cell protection, I have 3-series (3-S) Li-Po cell battery pack so I am using three of this integrated circuit to protect each cell.
My schematic is this:
[image]

The modules of this BMS are the following:
[image]

So my analysis about the operation is this: The modules DW01A IC1, IC2, IC3, can detect an event of overcharge, overdischarge, overcurrent, and short current as stated in the  DW01A datasheet.

[image]

For example, if a DW01A detects overcharge release voltage: (4.1V) as stated in datasheet, the OC pin will have a logic level voltage and it will active the associate PNP transistor which is an [MMBT5401](https://www.mouser.mx/datasheet/2/345/mmbt5401-1396157.pdf), how could I know that the transistor will be activated succesfully? which one is the right parameter of its datasheet? and then, the current will flow until the [BFS20](https://www.mouser.mx/datasheet/2/849/bfs20-2577250.pdf) NPN bjt transistor so it will activate the Gate of the associate MOSFETs which are [PSMN6R5-25YLC](https://www.mouser.mx/datasheet/2/916/PSMN6R5_25YLC-1544589.pdf) (I read this is a logic level MOSFET so I guess it should work, is that right?) and this will open the circuit so no current flows from CELL3 to CELL_GND, is that correct?

Could somebody tell me if I am right? do you think my design will work?
Thank you a lot!

[image]

This is the functional block diagram of the DW01A which indicates the logic level voltage:
[image]

The reference project of my schematic was taken from a [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYrftE13UzE)

This is the schematic:
[image]

Comment: The link to the DW01A datasheet is on a site that requires activating Javascript. I'm not going to do that for a site I don't know. Please link the appropriate datasheet from a source that doesn't require us to lower our browser's defenses just to download a PDF.

Comment: could you try to check the updated link please? now it is reference to JLCPCB part and it has datasheet download option, thank you in advance

Comment: It's a two-step process, not a direct link, but it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a problem with the BJTs you are using.

The [DW01A IC](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1901091236_PUOLOP-DW01A_C351410.pdf) expects the gate of N-channel MOSFETs to be connected to its OC and OD terminals instead of the base of BJTs.

[image]

I doubt that is going to work.

In particular the OC and OD pins can't source the current needed to drive a BJT as a switch. In fact look at the specs in the datasheet:

[image]

The output voltage at high level for OD, for example, is specified at a scant 10uA current, and no specification for the maximum output current for those pins is specified. This is a strong hint that they are not meant to source/sink too much current.

Moreover, look at the maximum voltage at low level (DoutL), it's 0.5V, more than enough to make a BJT barely conduct. This means that it could be impossible, in some cases, to turn the BJT off.

In addition, I suspect the presence of the MOSFETs body diodes is also needed to allow a correct operation during the transition from ON to OFF of those MOSFETs in series.

In general you should avoid using an IC specifically design to drive MOSFETs to drive BJTs, especially in this case, when the datasheets says nothing about the internal driver circuitry.

Comment: I just added the reference project schematic and the youtube tutorial which I saw for reference, do you really think it won't work? since I have seen many tutorials from that guy and he knows about electronics :( Thank you a lot

Comment: @imt_blake My Spanish is not so good. I skimmed over the video, but I couldn't understand whether he actually built the circuit and tested it or if he compared it to already made modules found on the market. To me it wasn't clear if he was analyzing a design of his or if he reverse engineered that green module he showed.

Comment: That is correct! he reverse engineered to the off the shelf green module and then changed a part which corresponds to the BJTs which are logic level, so I guess it works but I do not understand in detail the transistors topic

Comment: @imt_blake Anyway, every time an application-specific chip is used outside its intended reference application the design should be heavily tested to avoid surprises. Again, I'm not convinced the BJTs are guaranteed to be turned on/off in every conditions, given the worst-case values given in the datasheet. For example, assume Cell3 is at 2V, then OD1 min value could be Vdd-0.4=1.6V. Hence Q12 is biased with (1.6V-0.6V)/510k=2uA in its base. Is it sufficiently low to guarantee Q12 will be off?

Answer (score 1):

DW01A is not great for Li-Po batteries. I would argue that Overdischarge Protection Voltage of 2.5 Volts might be a bit too low for a Li-Po battery. Some manufacturers state that 2.75 V is recommended discharge voltage. Difference between 2.5 and 2.75 is less than a couple per cent of total charge. So staying on a safer side is probably better.

I think you can get away with it if you plan to use this system for high current applications, or don't expect it to get too low often. But if it's not the case than FS312F-G is probably better. It has the same application circuit.

Plus, yeah, using MOSFETs would be better. And the best of course is to use active battery cell balancing.